# Regex expected to match one letter matches whole word

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this expression in a switch statement for a script controlpanel

```
        $ctrlinpt=read-host ">>>"
        switch -regex ( $ctrlinpt )
        {
            <#1#>'^\w{2,}|\d{2,}$' { do this  }
            <#2#>'^c{1}|C{1}$' { do that }
            <#3#>'^l{1}|L{1}$' { do somethign else }
            <#4#>'^s{1}|S{1}$' { take a break }
            <#5#>'^exit$'{ go home }
        }
```

The first condition should match any input with more than one character and it does. However , if the input starts with one of the letters in the other conditions, it also matches their cases
for example

```
"Task1" matches only case 1
"Legacy" matches case 1 and case 3
"supper" matches case 1 and case 4
```

I expect cases 2,3, and 4 to only match an input of exactly the one character stated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `'^l{1}|L{1}$'` to `'^l$'` (regex matching is case-insensitive in PowerShell by default) and so on

Comment: game changer, thanks. I only added the quantifiers as an attempt to resolve this behavior. Any idea why it wont accept my solution (minus the quantifier)?

Comment: yeah the anchors`^`/`$` are interpreted as part of the subexpressions on either side of the alternation `|`, see answer below

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `'^l{1}|L{1}$'` is interpreted as "a string starting with `l` OR a string ending with `L`" - and since PowerShell does case-**i**nsensitive comparisons by default, "a string starting with `l`" perfectly describes `Legacy`.

To fix this, you can nest the alternation in a grouping construct:

```
^(?:l{1}|L{1})$
```

... or use a character class:

```
^[lL]$
```

... or, since the matches are case-insensitive by default anyway, simply match on a single character literal:

```
^l$
```

Thus, your switch becomes:

```
$ctrlinpt = read-host ">>>"
switch -regex ( $ctrlinpt ) {
    '^(?:\w{2,}|\d{2,})$' { do this }
    '^c$' { do that }
    '^l$' { do somethign else }
    '^s$' { take a break }
    '^exit$' { go home }
}
```

Since regex isn't really required for the last 4 cases, I'd suggest removing the `-regex` mode switch altogether and use a predicate for the first case instead:

```
$ctrlinpt = read-host ">>>"
switch ( $ctrlinpt ) {
    { $_ -match '^(?:\w{2,}|\d{2,})$' } { do this }
    'c' { do that }
    'l' { do somethign else }
    's' { take a break }
    'exit' { go home }
}
```